# Warning: Illegal string offset 'value' customer configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, customer, fatal-error

When i open 'customer configuration' from the `system configuration`, I got the  fatal error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'value'  in
>   httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php
>   on line 111

This fatal error only appears when i select a website value different than 'default config'.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with PHP 5.4+

You should NEVER rewrite core files unless absolutely necessary.

1. Create a new file:

   > app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php
2. Copy contents from

   > app/code/**core**/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php **to** 
   >   app/code/**local**/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php
3. Replace **line 111** with the following: `} elseif ((isset($v['value'])) && ($v['value']==$defText)) {`

This should correct your error.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about PHP version but Magento itself. For sure it has been FIXED in 1.9.3.2, maybe even earlier :)
It looks like this:

```
if ($options) {
  $defTextArr = array();
  foreach ($options as $k=>$v) {
    if ($isMultiple) {
        if (is_array($v['value']) && in_array($k, $v['value'])) {
            $defTextArr[] = $v['label'];
        }
    } elseif (isset($v['value'])) {
        if ($v['value'] == $defText) {
            $defTextArr[] = $v['label'];
            break;
        }
    } elseif (!is_array($v)) {
        if ($k == $defText) {
            $defTextArr[] = $v;
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  $defText = join(', ', $defTextArr);
}
```